# Working with strings with PHP, MySql, Javascript. Store in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

Hy everyone, as a self-taught junior programmer I never fully understood how to handle strings correctly.

For example what is the reason why if I write this `"Cos'ì è l'amore"` in the database it store me like this `"Cos\'ì è l\'amore"`.
Where I can read up well, I think it's the string encode, but I can't find anything that explains it well.

I'm having this result using AJAX for requests, where I create a javascript object and send to the server so it's treated as an array. I use Worpress to save(update in this case) to the database using `$wpdb->update`.

My database column uses the Wordpress standard **utf8mb4_general_ci**. Maybe I'm wrong with sending
AJAX ?
`$.ajax({ method:'POST',url:bmajax_obj.ajax_url,data:{ 'action':'modify','_ajax_nonce': bmajax_obj.nonce,'id':$form.attr('data-bm-id'),'data':dataObj},success : function(){ $('form[id="form-modal-editing"]').attr('data-bm-changed',false); $('#modal-btn-save').attr('disabled',true);$('#modal-editing').modal('hide');},error : function(error){console.log(error);}});`

### More information.

My database data was imported from a csv file in **UTF-8.**

```
        function modify_handler() {

            check_ajax_referer( 'admin' );

            if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])){
            
            $id = wp_unslash( $_POST['id']);
            $data = $_POST['data'];

            $v = self::$BM_Query->set_post($id,$data);
            if($v)
                echo "Successfull";
            else
                echo "Failed";
            }
            wp_die();
        }
```

public function set_post($id,$data){

```
global $wpdb;

$keys = array(
  'num_ing',
  'num_coll',
        'title',
        'author',
        'catalog',
        'year'
);

$metakeys = array('editor','category','section','tags', 'extract', 'rif_ing', 'rif_coll');

$dataObj = array();
$meta = array();

if( is_array($id) || empty(($id)) )
  return false;

if(!is_array($data))
  return false;

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

  if(!in_array($key,$keys) && in_array($key,$metakeys))
    $meta[$key] = $value;
  else
    $dataObj[$key] = $value;
    
}

$dataObj['meta'] = json_encode($meta);

if(is_numeric($id)){

  $wpdb->update($this->tablename,$dataObj,array('id'=>$id));
  return $dataObj['meta'];
}
```

}

### Finally I found the solution.

In the `modify_handler` function I hadn't passed the string into `wp_unslash`.

Since I'm very beginner, could you explain to me why we need to pass strings in `wp_unslash` ?

Comment: The ajax request shouldn't cause any data to be escaped. Please provide a [mre] of the issue including the exact database commands, and how you process the submitted data in PHP before you put it into the query. Are you using prepared statements and parameters, as you should? My guess is probably not, and that may be related to the issue. Alternatively it could be something to do with how you connect to the DB. Have you verified that the slashes are not inserted by PHP before you pass them to the DB? More debugging required, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've posted my functions just in case. But I found the solution.
Although I don't understand why. It would be nice to get an explanation.